# File containing a list of all installed software, including dependencies?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, files, dependencies

All the guides I've seen recommend the use of the command `dpkg --get-selections` and redirecting the output to a text file.

Isn't there a file somewhere on the filesystem that contains a list of all installed software, including dependencies? **A file that is updated every time the a package/dependency is installed.**

Comment: Can I ask why using `dpkg --get-selections` isn't desirable? I just want to understand your situation better.

Comment: If I want to get access to the installed packages of one distribution while running another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is a file. It is `/var/lib/dpkg/status` although this file is not going to be really useful if you want to get 'just' the list of installed packages. As you can see from the output below, this file has lot more information including dependencies, maintainer, version, architecture, etc.

```
ron@ron:~$ head /var/lib/dpkg/status
Package: fonts-sil-abyssinica
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: fonts
Installed-Size: 2208
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: all
Multi-Arch: foreign
Version: 1.500-1
Replaces: ttf-sil-abyssinica (<< 1.200-1)
```

Comment: `$ ls -tl /var/lib/dpkg/info/ | grep list > installed-packages.txt` ...